# Is there way to know when a column value was updated in SqlServer?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to know when a column value has been updated in sql server, as far I know don't have any way, but, anyone know a way? (Log files, query cache, etc.)

**EDIT**

I need to know when a column value was updated before this question is asked. So, create a trigger don't help me

Comment: "I need to know when a column value was updated before this question is asked." What does that mean?  Before what "question" is asked?

Comment: @roryap sorry my english,  before THIS question, so triggers don't help-me.

Comment: @roryap I can't create a trigger in the pass!! haha

Comment: I still don't understand.  Why can't you create a trigger?

Comment: Oh, I think I understand now.  You need to know when the value was updated historically.  In that case, you're right: a trigger will only help going forward.

Comment: @roryap yeah! exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [an update trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx).  Inside the trigger, you can examine the particular column whose value you're interested in monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

The [sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYS.DM_DB_INDEX_USAGE_STATS_TSQL%29;k%28SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1%29;k%28SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1%29;k%28MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT%29;k%28DevLang-TSQL%29&rd=true) DMV is about as good as you can get without setting up something more proactive like an UPDATE trigger or special column:

```
SELECT DB_NAME(database_id) AS DBName, 
        OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id, database_id) AS SchemaName, 
        OBJECT_NAME(object_id, database_id) AS ObjectName, 
        last_user_update, 
        last_system_update
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE last_system_update IS NOT NULL 
    OR last_user_update IS NOT NULL
```

Hope that helps,

John